# ReactJS: Save input value on blur and not on every key stroke

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onblur, react-props, getderivedstatefromprops

I have created a React View, say `MyView`, which has 2 text inputs whose initial values will be passed by parent read from a DB.

I also want the changed values to be saved back to DB. So, the view is also passed a callback function for the same.

**Consider that DB save operation is heavy and you should not do it very frequently**. So, I decided to listen to `onBlur` events instead of `onChange` events on the input boxes as `onChange` is invoked on every key stroke.

**First Approach:**

```
class MyView extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
              <input type="url" value={this.props.values.A}
                   onBlur={(evt)=>{this.props.saveValue('A', evt.target.value)}} />
              <input type="url" value={this.props.values.B}
                   onBlur={(evt)=>{this.props.saveValue('B', evt.target.value)}} />         

              <button type="button" onClick={this.props.resetValues}>Reset</button>
            </div>
        );
     }
}
```

However, this does not work as `React` enforces a controlled input (with `value` attribute) always to be accompanied by an `onChange` listener.

**Second Approach:**

So, I tried to make these inputs as `uncontrolled`. That is, instead of `value` attribute, used `defaultValue`.

```
<input type="url" defaultValue={this.props.values.A}
       onBlur={(evt)=>{this.props.saveValue('A', evt.target.value)}} />
```

But this also did not work as on reset/clear button click, although the view was made to re-render but `defaultValue` does not update once view is created.

**Third Approach:**

So, I finally added an `onChange` listener but as no-op.

```
<input type="url" value={this.props.values.A}
       onChange={()=>{console.log('do nothing')}
       onBlur={(evt)=>{this.props.saveValue('A', evt.target.value)}} />
```

Again, this did not work as the view re-renders after calling `onChange` and since value is not reflected in `props` yet, `value` seems to reset back to initial on every key stroke.

**Fourth Approach:**

Last I tried was to maintain a `state` in component and read value from state and on every `onChange` save the value back to state. This worked to most extent but whenever there were external changes to props and the view was re-rendered, `state` did not update. So, I added a `getDerivedStateFromProps` function to view:

```
static getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state) {
    return props.values;
}
```

Now, this again did not work. Reason being that this function is invoked even if I temporarily save values to state and the state was reset to initial values in props.

Can some ReactJS expert help me with my use-case?

Comment: As some first information, did the onChange work? Did it send the data to the database when it changed?

Comment: @Craws If I use `onChange` instead of `onBlur`, yes, it totally works but I don't want to fire save on database on every key stroke.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going by the comments on Liren Yeo's solution, I would handle the props-state reconciliation on `componentDidUpdate`, where you get both the old `state` and `props`. This way you can determine how `this.props` was updated and act accordingly. When the value in `props` does not match `state` nor `oldProps`, the update is external and you should override the unsaved changes in the state.

The code should look something like this

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {

if (this.props.values !== prevProps.values && this.props.values !== this.state.values) {
  this.setState({values:this.props.values});
   }
}
```

If you go this route, you can also leave the input `uncontrolled` and update its value through a reference. This solves some unreliability with `controlled` inputs, like for example, a `type='number'` returning `undefined` as its value when you type a decimal comma. You still need to store the value `onChange` but only save it `onBlur` and handling the state-prop-dom reconciliation in `componentDidUpdate`

Comment: Awesome! Thanks @diego. This is what I was looking for. :)

Answer (score 4):

You will still need `onChange` to help you set the states of both url input. `onBlur` is only used to trigger saving, it's 2 different events for different purposes.

Since your A & B values are passed down from parent component. `MyView`'s parent component should pass down `this.state.values` and the functions to set the state.

Refer to this snippet if everything is in single component. You should be able move `handleChange` function up to its parent component.

```js
class App extends React.Component {

  state = {
    values: {
      A: '',
      B: ''
    }
  }

  handleChange = e => {
    this.setState({
      values: {
      ...this.state.values,
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value
    })
  }

  handleBlur = e => {
    if (e.target.name === 'A') {
      alert(`Saving A: ${this.state.values.A}`)
    }

    if (e.target.name === 'B') {
      alert(`Saving B: ${this.state.values.B}`)
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <label>Value A</label>
        <input
          type="url"
          name="A"
          value={this.state.values.B}
          onChange={this.handleChange}
          onBlur={this.handleBlur}
        />
        <label>Value B</label>
        <input
          type="url"
          name="B"
          value={this.state.values.A}
          onChange={this.handleChange}
          onBlur={this.handleBlur}
        />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
</div>
```

---

**EDIT:** Your fourth approach should work with the following:

```
static getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state) {
  return { values: props.values }
}

constructor(props) {
  super(props)
  this.state = {
    values: props.values
  }
}
```

so basically the `this.state.values` is the final source of truth. When user types something, you `setState` in this component and change it. But if `props.values` changes (from external source), `getDerivedStateFromProps` will update the values state.

Comment: Thanks @liren-yeo. My use-case is to read initial values from `this.props` but at the same time reflect to any new changes in `this.props` happening internally or externally.

Comment: @lazyvab May I know what triggers the changes on `this.props.values`? Is it that user can type inside the URL input?

Comment: You may assume `this.props.values` to be changed from 3 places - first on user input, second on reset button click, third externally from a different service. But in case of external changes, the parent container takes care of re-rendering the view like: `ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(MyView, {..props}`

Comment: @lazyvab when external changes happen, do you still want to trigger the save immediately?

Comment: By external changes, I mean that there is a parallel component which already saves values in DB and I want to reflect those updates in this view. So, no further save required. Just view render with new values.

Comment: regarding your suggestion to use `getDerivedStateFromProps`, as I already mentioned in question, this function is invoked even if `state` is changed. But this function will reset state to what was available in props. Please note that the state has some unsaved changes which are yet not available in props.

Answer (score 0):

So with the idea that onChange works, I would recommend you to take a look at this:

https://schier.co/blog/2014/12/08/wait-for-user-to-stop-typing-using-javascript.html
Navigate to the heading: **Wait for Typing to Stop**

Hope it can somehow lead you to what you want to achieve.

Comment: Thanks @craws for sharing it. Yes, it can be one approach where I don't use `onBlur` but use time-based `onChange`. But for this particular use-case, I don't want it to be time-based as in my actual code, there are other inputs as well like textarea which will contain a long text and I cannot afford firing multiple DB save requests.

Comment: A "Jenky" solution would be to set states per input field and triggering a setState after a onChange. Allowing a database request after all states are valid/notNull.

Comment: can you please help me with some code snippet or example? Are you asking to trigger a dummy `setState` which is equivalent to re-render? If you get me, the basic problem is that the values are read from props but updated in state whereas props are updated at a later stage.